# NSOpenPanel as sheet

Tags: swift, nsopenpanel

Ive looked around at other answers, but nothing seems to be helping my case.

I have a viewController class which contains an IBAction for a button. This button should open a NSOpenPanel as a sheet from that viewController:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
@IBAction func folderSelection(sender: AnyObject) {
    var myFiledialog: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    myFiledialog.prompt = "Select path"
    myFiledialog.worksWhenModal = true
    myFiledialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    myFiledialog.canChooseDirectories = true
    myFiledialog.canChooseFiles = false
    myFiledialog.resolvesAliases = true

    //myFiledialog.runModal()

    myFiledialog.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!, completionHandler: nil)


    var chosenpath = myFiledialog.URL
    if (chosenpath!= nil)
    {
        var TheFile = chosenpath!.absoluteString!
        println(TheFile)
        //do something with TheFile
    }
    else
    {
        println("nothing chosen")
    }
}
}
```

The problem comes from myFileDialog.beginSheetModalForWindow(..) , it works with the line above, but that is not a sheet effect

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to call `beginSheetModalForWindow` from your panel on your window, and use a completion block:

```
let myFiledialog = NSOpenPanel()
myFiledialog.prompt = "Select path"
myFiledialog.worksWhenModal = true
myFiledialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false
myFiledialog.canChooseDirectories = true
myFiledialog.canChooseFiles = false
myFiledialog.resolvesAliases = true
myFiledialog.beginSheetModalForWindow(window, completionHandler: { num in
    if num == NSModalResponseOK {
        let path = myFiledialog.URL
        print(path)
    } else {
        print("nothing chosen")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

```swift
let dialog = NSOpenPanel()
dialog.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!){ result in
    if result == .OK, let url = dialog.url {
        print("Got", url)
    }
}
```