# URL saveAs extension

Tags: swift, url, nssavepanel

When this URL extension is run as a panel it fails to return a URL, seemingly bypassing the completion:

```
func saveAs() -> URL? {
    let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
    var saveAsURL : URL? = nil

    savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = self.lastPathComponent
    savePanel.directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    if let keyWindow = NSApp.keyWindow {
        savePanel.beginSheetModal(for: keyWindow, completionHandler: { result in
            /*if result == .OK {*/ saveAsURL = savePanel.url //}
        })
    }
    else
    {
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)

        if savePanel.runModal() == .OK {
            saveAsURL = savePanel.url
        }
    }
    Swift.print("saveAsURL => \(saveAsURL.debugDescription)")

    return saveAsURL
}
```

but run as standalone window it works fine.  There is another related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59772633/564870) but here the usage is different: i.e.

```
guard let saveAsURL = URL.init(string: "download.dmg").saveAs() else { return }
```

where I presume a user cancel would infer the processing should end.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `.runModal` your code does a very, very odd thing: it *stops* and waits for the user to deal with the modal dialog (also known as *blocking*). That goes back to the extremely early days of OS X / Cocoa, and is an anomaly in behavior. So the result is that by the time we get to the end of the method and your `Swift.print` and `return`, we are *back* from the modal dialog and we have the value from it.

But, as I say, that's totally weird. (In fact, I'm not sure I can think of any other Cocoa call that acts like that.) The `.beginSheetModal` call behaves normally, i.e. after the call your code goes right on and gets to the end with the `print` and `return` *before* the modal sheet even has a chance to appear. What happens within the modal sheet then happens *asynchronously* with respect the calling code here — i.e. *later*. Thus you cannot return any value from the dialog because you'd need a time machine to look into the future. That is the standard pattern for this sort of thing.

Comment: If the term "asynchronous" is strange to you, you might want to read http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Comment: Yes, exactly but then the referenced answer presumed correct, I cannot otherwise see why an extension would behave differently?  One plausible solution I'm thinking would to pass the saveAs() a completion handler but I'm confused if the other answer works?  I in-lined my extension and yeah same behavior so perhaps the completion() is the only solution? But still confused between these two.

Comment: I can't help you with some _other_ question. I believe what I'm saying to be correct about _your_ code, and it should be easy to confirm it just by lacing your code heavily with more `print` statements.

Comment: Yes you right of course, my original question and its context was re: its use as an extension vs the other answer as it was in-line; yet both exhibit the same behavior described. In olden days the sheet completion was better understood I think.

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with following my suggestion re: a completion handler.

```
func saveAs(responseHandler: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
    let savePanel = NSSavePanel()

    savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = self.lastPathComponent
    savePanel.directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    if let keyWindow = NSApp.keyWindow {
        savePanel.beginSheetModal(for: keyWindow, completionHandler: { result in
            responseHandler( result == .OK ? savePanel.url : nil )
         })
    }
    else
    {
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)

        let result = savePanel.runModal()
        responseHandler( result == .OK ? savePanel.url : nil )
    }
}
```

and called like this - response delegate; the user clicked a download link on a 'data' (binary) file known by its UTI, so we download then get back to the earlier URL:

```
    guard url.hasDataContent(), let suggestion = response.suggestedFilename else { decisionHandler(.allow); return }
    let downloadDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let saveURL = downloadDir.appendingPathComponent(suggestion)
    saveURL.saveAs(responseHandler: { saveAsURL in
        if let saveAsURL = saveAsURL {
            self.loadFileAsync(url, to: saveAsURL, completion: { (path, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    NSApp.presentError(error)
                }
                else
                {
                    if appDelegate.isSandboxed() { _ = appDelegate.storeBookmark(url: saveAsURL, options: [.withSecurityScope]) }
                }
            })
        }

        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        self.backPress(self)
     })
```

I think I like the older way better ;-)